# SQL error 150 on table creation

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I know the error 150 is related to foreign keys, but i can't figure out what wrong here.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(

   id_user INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   prenom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   naissance DATE NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Livre(
   id_livre INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   titre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   parution DATE NOT NULL,
   id_edit INT NOT NULL,
   id_user INT NOT NULL,

   FOREIGN KEY ( id_edit)
   REFERENCES Editeur(id_edit)
   ON DELETE CASCADE,

   FOREIGN KEY ( id_user)
   REFERENCES User(id_user)
   ON DELETE CASCADE      

);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Publication(

   id_pub INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   texte TEXT NOT NULL,
   date_pub DATE NOT NULL,
   titre_pub VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   id_livre INT NOT NULL,
   id_user INT NOT NULL,

   FOREIGN KEY ( id_user)
   REFERENCES User(id_user)
   ON DELETE CASCADE,

   FOREIGN KEY (id_livre)
   REFERENCES Livre(id_livre)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Editeur(
   id_edit INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   pays VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   adresse VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   tel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

);
```

The error occurs when i try to create tables Livre and Publication.
Types are the same so it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I would recommend using the SSMS GUI to create tables since it's so easy - but, at the very least, script the tables individually so that your errors are easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

By mindful of the ***order*** in which you create the tables.

For instance, your table creation statement for `Livre` defines a foreign key on `Editeur`.  But the table `Editeur` has not been created yet.

Adjust the `create table` statement ordering as required.